# How to transfer function to a class?

Tags: python

I write a class and in `__init__`, I want to transfer a callback function as `action` and use in this class

But the `action` value in `print(self.action)` and `print(action)` are `None`

Please help me solve the problem, thanks!

---

setInterval1.py

```
class setInterval :
    def __init__(self,interval,action) :
        self.interval=interval
        self.action=action
        print('--- init ---')
        print(self.action)
        print(action)
        print('------------')
        self.stopEvent=threading.Event()
        self.startTime=time.time()
        thread=threading.Thread(target=self.__setInterval)
        thread.start()

    def __setInterval(self) :
        nextTime=time.time()+self.interval
        while not self.stopEvent.wait(nextTime-time.time()):
            print('--- interval start ---')
            nextTime+=self.interval
            self.action()
```

main.py

```
def startP(data):
    print('--- startP ---')
    print(data)
    print('--------------')

inter=setInterval(5, startP(request.json))
```

Comment: Because you're passing the *return value* of `startP(request.json)` to `setInterval`, which is `None`…

Comment: Replace the last line with this **inter=setInterval(5, lambda :startP('request.json'))**